# How should I resolve a promise within a forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a function that loops through invoices and then calls an API to get back more detail about the invoices. I want to add that detail of the invoices to an array.

My code below, does get the invoice detail correctly but I cannot figure out how to add that invoice detail into the array, "invoices" is always [] for me. I think this has to do with how I need to resolve the promise from the API call?

```
//some other promise

var invoiceInfo = customerBalance.Rows.Row;

var customerInvoices = {
    "customerName": headerInfo[0].value,
    "customerId": headerInfo[0].id,
    "customerPhone": "",
    "invoices": []
}

invoiceInfo.forEach(function(invoice, index) {
    //only add overdue invoices
    if (invoice.ColData[3].value <= today) {
        if (invoice.ColData[1].value == "Invoice") {

            getInvoiceDetail(senderId, invoice.ColData[1].id).then(function(invoiceDetails) {
                customerInvoices.invoices.push(invoiceDetails);

                resolve(customerInvoices); //how should i resolve this?
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);

                reject(err);
            });
        }
    }                                        
});

console.log("CUSTOMER INVOICES: " + JSON.stringify(customerInvoices, null, 4));

overdueInvoices.push(customerInvoices);

//resolve some other promise
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your `getInvoiceDetail()` Function is returning the Promise, you can use `async/await`

```
var invoiceInfo = customerBalance.Rows.Row;
var customerInvoices = {
    "customerName": headerInfo[0].value,
    "customerId": headerInfo[0].id,
    "customerPhone": "",
    "invoices": []
}
invoiceInfo.forEach(async (invoice, index) => {
    if (invoice.ColData[3].value <= today) {
        if (invoice.ColData[1].value == "Invoice") {
            const invoiceDetails = await getInvoiceDetail(senderId, invoice.ColData[1].id)
            customerInvoices.invoices.push(invoiceDetails);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can promisify the function for getting the data, like this:

```js
const getInvoiceDetailPromisified = (senderId, id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getInvoiceDetail(senderId, id).then(
      invoiceDetails => {
        resolve(invoiceDetails); //how should i resolve this?
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      },
    );
  });
};
```

Promisifying is the art of transforming a function that receives a callback into a function that returns a callback

With that in mind, you can go through all the elements in `invoiceInfo` and map them to this promise like this:

```js
const customerInvoicesPromise = invoiceInfo.reduce((acc, invoice) => {
  // if its overdue append it do the accumulation as a promise
  if (invoice.ColData[3].value <= today && invoice.ColData[1].value == 'Invoice') {
    return acc.concat(getInvoiceDetailPromisified(senderId, invoice.ColData[1].id));
  }

  // else just return the transformation
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Then if you have access to async/await you could do

```js
const customerInvoices = await Promise.all(customerInvoicesPromise);
```

or if not you could just resolve the promise the standard way

```js
Promise.all(customerInvoicesPromise).then(data => {
  // do something
});
```

Promise.all takes an array of promises and it is resolved when each promise in the element is resolved. Well, it returns a Promise as well

Hope this helps!